# How to store historical data i

Tags: mysql, historical-db

I have a Mysql database with a large product table (ca. 700k rows and 35 columns) where every record (except for the PK variable) can be updated biweekly. Currently I included it in my database with the latest update. I want to store historical data for each update (e.g. from 1st of April 2021, 15th of April 2021, 1st of May 2021 ...). Is there a clever way to store such historical data in a run time friendly way without saving the 700k records of each biweekly update in a separate table?

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, i would ask this kind of thing in the dba forum

Comment: with mariadb you can use System-Versioned Tables. i am not sure if MySQL can do it also.
see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/

Comment: Do you know a good dba forum where I could as this question?